# trying to download a video from a streaming site, can't get the link i need

Tags: python, video, python-requests

so i just learned how to use the requests module (not much but i saw a couple videos) and i tried to download an episode of a series i like - 'Bull'.
so i found a function here that seems to work for a single file :

```
def download_file(url):
    local_filename = 'bull-season-2-ep-5.mp4'
    # NOTE the stream=True parameter
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    with open(local_filename, 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024): 
            if chunk: # filter out keep-alive new chunks
                f.write(chunk)
                #f.flush() commented by recommendation from J.F.Sebastian
    return local_filename

download_file(https://ww1.123movies.domains/tvseries/bull-season-2/9jpHC3uD/8J1Mx54O/wJbEvBiB-watch-free.html?start_watching=true&_=1567021316534")
```

but as you can see from the photo below, the file is broken down into many pieces so i can't download the whole file (when i inspected the web page its blob so i went to the network tab as you can see below).

[image]

i tried to use the first link as you can see but it doesn't work.
the only difference in the links that got created is the 'seg' number

for example this is one link:

https://stream-4-1.loadshare.org/stream/VideoID-5Xjczd53/Ry60dtNEZdzeDHMykqym7Wj-PVhL45OMuxLNI2rIH-0HUjnD6HhzRaxQFTUG3mfRHD-_lj-hgLrzI54m6b0homRf0HJWQVMx4uxcLDIM9tY8iy60-BfUFfNIoRvUuy8O/seg-15-v1-a1.ts?token=ip=93.173.86.29~st=1567021318~exp=1567035718~acl=/*~hmac=6eb03c58be1eb01ce659384c30e67291748d4c86679dfca47f77edcf9ee8ec37

another one:

https://stream-4-1.loadshare.org/stream/VideoID-5Xjczd53/Ry60dtNEZdzeDHMykqym7Wj-PVhL45OMuxLNI2rIH-0HUjnD6HhzRaxQFTUG3mfRHD-_lj-hgLrzI54m6b0homRf0HJWQVMx4uxcLDIM9tY8iy60-BfUFfNIoRvUuy8O/seg-20-v1-a1.ts?token=ip=93.173.86.29~st=1567021318~exp=1567035718~acl=/*~hmac=6eb03c58be1eb01ce659384c30e67291748d4c86679dfca47f77edcf9ee8ec37

does anyone have a fix?
thank you!

Comment: Your link doesnt work: `https://ww1.123movies.domains/tvseries/bull-season- 
2/9jpHC3uD/8J1Mx54O/wJbEvBiB-watch-free.html? 
start_watching=true&_=1567021316534`

Comment: that's just the first link that get's created in the network tab, if you try one of the others, it will work, i just downloaded a 5 secs video with one of them

Comment: to download all the segments of a segmented MP$ (HLS or DASH) you will need to locate the manifest (eg m3u8) and parse that and request the segments that make up the video.

Comment: well, i've checked all of the segments in the network tab, none of them had m3u8. this subject is quite new to me, can you please provide more explanation?

Comment: Look for `master.m3u8`. [Example link](https://stream-4-1.loadshare.org/stream/VideoID-5Xjczd53/Ry60dtNEZdzeDHMykqym7Wj-PVhL45OMuxLNI2rIH-0HUjnD6HhzRaxQFTUG3mfRHD-_lj-hgLrzI54m6b0homRf0HJWQVMx4uxcLDIM9tY8iy60-BfUFfNIoRvUuy8O/master.m3u8?token=ip=86.187.160.71~st=1567024191~exp=1567038591~acl=/*~hmac=35b4ef868b0e773b14719c57df5cd9bc76c2aaefddc62e67e1649a0e7bfa370d) (token might be expired now)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests
import m3u8

def download_file(url):

    local_filename = 'video.ts'
    r = requests.get(url)
    m3u8_master = m3u8.loads(r.text)
    playlist_url = m3u8_master.data['playlists'][0]['uri']
    full_url = url.split('/')
    full_url = "/".join(full_url[0:-2])
    full_url += '/'

    playlist_url = full_url + playlist_url
    new_r = requests.get(playlist_url)
    playlist = m3u8.loads(new_r.text)

    with open(local_filename, 'wb') as f:
        for segment in playlist.data['segments']:
            url = full_url + segment['uri']
            req = requests.get(url)
            f.write(req.content)

download_file("https://stream-4-1.loadshare.org/stream/VideoID-uJzosrrC/JToU5G8Qcw4SHs0l5HOqkCAtsSRhJvI2h2viOe9gMFgxLwl5PZPWQn4kV3zA14s5Opr9Z-poO9unm7L3I2XsjShpoq9CezUZJWqeOBwO8bbM3wFByH_hHteLDBeCi7yF/master.m3u8?token=ip=93.173.86.29~st=1567117245~exp=1567131645~acl=/*~hmac=7926c25f1766c342bd21a2273901ce3b1a83b6b8461a861175efc0588bbaae7e")
```

so this function works.. i got some help from this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bytnxnZFLeg&t=232s if someone wants to get a more detailed explanation.

i had to go to the network tab and find the 'master.m3u8' request and from there try to seperate the different segments and concatenate them into a single file like Offbeatmammal and VC.One said. Thank you.